# Uncaught Error: Couldn't find a Layout component in the rendered component tree

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm receiving an error with Iron Router 0.7.0 on Meteor 0.8.0.

Within the UI.Compenent.lookup function in blaze-layout's layout.js, the following error is triggering:

> Uncaught Error: Couldn't find a Layout component in the rendered component tree

It's hard to know exactly what is causing this error and what isn't working because of it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that your yields are correct. Instead of `{{yield 'title'}}` you should now have `{{> yield region='title'}}`.

Comment: Are you overriding the Router's rendering or using the Layout template directly?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have any named yields, so I checked to make sure all my other templates were named correctly. Eventually, I discovered my main.html didn't require a {{> yield}} within the <body> tag. Is this new or just not throwing an error in previous versions?

Comment: @cmather I am having the same problem. Can you explain more about overriding the Router's rendering or using the Layout template directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just got the same error, for me it was caused by including my layout template within `<body>`, and specifying it as the `layoutTemplate` option. To fix it, I removed the include from `<body>`.

Here is a before and after of my code;

example.html (before)

```
<head>
  <title>example</title>
</head>

<body>
   {{>layout}}
</body>

<template name="layout">
    <div>{{>yield}}</div>
</template>
```

example.js (before)

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

}
```

example.html (after)

```
<head>
  <title>example</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="layout">
    <div>{{>yield}}</div>
</template>
```

example.js (after -- same as before)